# Orion CB output regarding provisioned device

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have noticed that upon querying Orion CB, while it is working with provisioned devices and having IoT Agent receive HTTP and MQTT messages, it will always output all the values written in the quotation marks:

```
{
    "id": "sensor_data",
    "type": "Sensor",
    "ActiveTime": {
        "type": "Seconds",
        "value": "17703",
        "metadata": {
            "TimeInstant": {
                "type": "ISO8601",
                "value": "2018-07-04T13:32:27.357Z"
            }
        }
    },
    "Distance": {
        "type": "Number",
        "value": "312",
        "metadata": {
            "TimeInstant": {
                "type": "ISO8601",
                "value": "2018-07-04T13:32:27.413Z"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, if to work with only entities in Orion CB, it is possible to receive actual values (like in the example in the manual):

```
{
"id": "Room1",
"pressure": {
    "metadata": {},
    "type": "Integer",
    "value": 720
},
"temperature": {
    "metadata": {},
    "type": "Float",
    "value": 23
},
"type": "Room"
}
```

Sometimes, I need to receive the actual value from my sensor in order to format it and use in further applications, but they are in quotation marks, which makes it a little difficult.
Is it possible to somehow change?(maybe in device provisioning), or it really should be that way regarding devices?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**
This is the way I provisioned the device:

```
{ 
"devices": [ 
    { 
        "device_id": "sensor_data", 
        "entity_name": "sensor_data", 
        "entity_type": "Sensor",
        "transport": "MQTT",
        "timezone": "Europe/Helsinki",
        "attributes": [ 
           { "object_id": "act", "name": "ActiveTime", "type": "Seconds"},
           { "object_id": "dst", "name": "Distance", "type": "Number"}
        ]
    }
]
}
```

And this is how the MQTT messages are sent from my sensor (I have set up the topics for IoT Agent to understand them)

> /123456789/sensor_data/attrs/act 12
>   /123456789/sensor_data/attrs/dst 322

123456789 is the API Key I have set here.

Comment: I think I know the anser (or, at least, and aproximation to the answer :) but before answering the question... which IOTA are you using? IOTA-JSON? IOTA-UL? Other? Thanks!

Comment: @fgalan IoTA UL 2.0 . I have received a suggestion from aside, that I should activate autocast inside of Orion Context Broker?

Comment: @fgalan Nope, autocast did not help here. Values remain in string format.

Comment: A couple of additional questions, pls... to narrow down the case. How are you provisioning the device at IOTA-UL (i.e. `POST /iot/device` request used to create the device at IOTA)? How are you sending measures in both MQTT and HTTP cases? Please, edit your question to include that information.

Comment: @fgalan Yes, the device is provisioned through a POST /iot/device API, measures are sent through using MQTT messages with the topics set in a way for IoT Agent to understand.
Question edited with the missing info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation tipycally happens when IoT Agents uses NGSIv1 to push data to Context Broker, given that NGSIv1 always "string-fy" any attribute value. Recently, the ability to use NGSIv2 (which doesn't have this limitatino) was introduced in IoT Agents.

In order to solve your problem you have to:

- Use a recent IOTA-UL version (the current one from master branch will work)
- Enable NGSIv2 in configuration as explained [in documentation](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/master/doc/installationguide.md#global-configuration). This is done in the `config.js` file:

  ```
  config.iota = {
    ...    
       contextBroker: {
       ...
       ngsiVersion: 'v2'
    }
  ...
  }
  ```

  or using environament variable `IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION=v2` for the IOTA-UL process.
- Enable autocast as explained [in documentation](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/tree/master/docs/usermanual.md#casting-to-json-native-format). This is done in `config.js` file:

  ```
  config.iota = {
    ...    
    autocast: true,
    ...
  }
  ```

  or using environament variable `IOTA_AUTOCAST=true` for the IOTA-UL process.
- Set the right type for each attribute at provision time. The [documentation here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/tree/master/docs/usermanual.md#casting-to-json-native-format)) provides the right types:

  > - Type "Number" for integer or float numbers
  > - Type "Boolean" for boolean
  > - Type "None" for null

  Thus, in your case the provisioning for `Distance` is ok, but for `ActiveTime` you should use also `Number` as `type`.

Comment: Strange enough, just today I have installed a new IoT Agent and was configuring the config.js file... How didn't I see those things?
Anyway, thank you very much, gonna give it a try tomorrow morning and then notify whether I suceeded or not!

Comment: Maybe the explanation is that these options are not in the the config.js template. Note the config.js file in the repository root is an useful template but not always complete. The full information is in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! Everything really does work! You have saved my life haha. 
Next time I will try to read documentation more carefully!

Comment: Have to return to this to clarify. While playing around with metadata persistance, I discovered that pretty much, IoT Agent can be set up to NGSI v1, with Autocast enabled and it still will not "stringify" the mentioned types. Moreover, as I just learned, even if IoT Agent is set to NGSI v2, it still will stringify the messages that are not of the mentioned types. Is it a bug/issue with IoT Agent NGSI v2???

Comment: I'm not getting the point, sorry... I think it would be a good idea to create a new question post about it, including the example needed to reproduce it (I'm afraid that the available space allowed in a comment it is not the best place to explain). Could you do it, please? Thanks!